# Can Manticore Parry redirect an attack towards the original attacker?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

The Tome of Battle supplement for D&D 3.5 offers a Maneuver called Manticore Parry, which allows the initiator to redirect the attack to another target. But which targets are legal?

> When you initiate this maneuver, you can attempt to block an enemy's melee attack that targets you and **redirect it to another target** adjacent to you. Make  a melee attack roll. If your result is greater than your foe's attack roll, you bat aside the strike and direct it **against a target of your choice that stands adjacent to you**.

...

> If you succeed in deflecting the
>   attack, use the result of your opponent’s attack roll to determine if it strikes **the new target**.

Emphasis mine.

Assuming that the attacker is adjacent to the initiator, is the original attacker a legal target? Or does the specification of "a new target" imply the necessity of a third party being present?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It implies nothing.**

The grammar of the sentence indicates that 'another target' is taking about a target besides *you*, the original victim of the attack. Manticore Parry indeed lets you cause your opponent to hit themselves with their own attacks.

Comment: "You cannot use it against unarmed attacks, natural weapons, or touch spells." is actually specified later in the description, but OK. :P

Comment: Baaaah! I think I forgot about that part because my group houseruled it away the moment we saw it. It was too funny the other way >.>

Answer (score 5):

My reading is this: “new” target is contrasted with the “old” target, i.e. you. Thus, the “new” target cannot be the same as the original target (which would be a waste). Aside from that, the target may be anyone “of your choice that stands adjacent to you,” including the original attacker.

Comment: For the information of future readers: This is a perfectly good answer, but I only had one "accept" tag.